# File downloader suggestions

Tags: c++, windows, url, download

I need to provide non-techie user ability to reliable download a few large files (3Gb) from URL without revealing the source URL of the file. Ideally I need single exe (without dependencies) that will download file from URL, specified inside exe: when user click on exe it just need show prompt where to save the file, and(optionally) will provide the user with some progress bar, for instance. The target URL can be specified directly in
the resource section, so I can edit URL path with HEX editor when I need set another path. 
Wget are not suitable in my case, as its command line utility and requires user to specify an URL.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Implement the [`IBindStatusCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to receive progress information.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't hide the source URL. Why are you trying to do that? If an end user runs tcpdump while they are running your program, they'll see where packets are coming from and going to.

Comment: User should not see the plain url. Sort of download manager which just help download large file. (similar with proprietary download managers offered by some companies to download their data).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just provide them with a small batch file which calls `ftp.exe`. Tell your end user to drop the .BAT file where the downloaded file should go, and click it.

That solves quite a few problems, e.g. you know that your end user will be able to find the directory.

Comment: These downloads via HTTP, not FTP.